# Is the UX site the correct place to ask color layout questions?

Tags: support, questions

I have a few questions where i am looking for feedback on some color layout on my website.  Is the UX appropriate place for this type of question?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options for you, depending on the type of question you have.

- If it's about colors, different color space, RGB or CMYK color model, transparent color, using or changing colors then probably Graphic Design Stack Exchange is the best place for you. [Here is a list of the questions on Graphic Design Stack Exchange tagged COLOR.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)
- If it's about things like how the use of color directly affects user experience - such as how color contrast affects people with low vision, or if you want to use color to call attention to specific elements of a page / app then this User Experience site is probably the best place for it. [Here is a list of the User Experience questions on the site that have been tagged with the COLOR tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)
- If you're wanting a general review of a colourscheme you've implemented then unfortunately none of the stackexchange sites are suitable for that sort of thing, as we're not really here to give general reviews of sites as that doesn't provide any benefit to other users of the site other than the person asking the question (Stack Exchange is designed as a repository for useful questions and answers that many people may have - a bit more like Wikipedia than Yahoo Answers).

So it really depends what your question is. Hopefully we can help, provided it's a question that has a hypothetical correct answer and isn't just a 'what do you think of this color' type question.

Comment: thanks . . i will frame my question appropriate for the UX site given the guidance above